# Page return blank when clicked button performs .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***functionality***

User clicks on a button in the menu page and it will navigate user to the next page.

***What has been done:***

Have created 2 separate .html file and when button is clicked it will perform

```
$("#").load("*.html");
```

method.

***Issue:***

When user clicks on the button from the menu page, it navigates the user to a blank page instead of showing the user the correct content from the new page.

Hence, what has happen and what has gone wrong? It seems strange as it should rightfully work and load the new .html file when clicked.

```js
$("#Game").click(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
  $("#Game").attr("disabled", true);

  $("#jigsaw_ReadyPage").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#div_play").empty();
    $("#div_play").load("SDW.html");
    $("#div_play").fadeIn();
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="jigsaw_ReadyPage" style="height: 1920px; width: 1080px; background-image: url(lib/img/Page02.png);">

  <button id="Game"></button>
</div>
<div id="div_play"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the path to the file? ('./SDW.html') or the full path?

Comment: @Cruiser the current file is in the same path name as the SDW.html. Hence, the path is just named as SDW.html

Comment: which will work for your localhost but not on a server

Comment: @Cruiser  I am using a localhost. Tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8080/. and its not really working there